# iPad incorrect rendering of Objects

Tags: xcode, macos, ipad, ios-simulator

We just set up a whole bunch of development MacBooks in our office.  We all set up the computers exactly the same as far as I can tell (just installing xcode and not changing any settings).  We even distributed the exact same xcode project to everyone to test whether or not everyone was set up correctly.  For some reason though, my iPad simulator incorrectly renders the positions of Objects on the UIView controller.
I can make a really basic application and slap down a UIView controller with the storyboard editor in xcode 4.3.1 (newest version ATM), and add a button to it.  When I run this on the simulator, it will look fine on the iPhone one, but when I try to view it in the iPad, it seems that some elements will scale to the iPad resolution fine, but others will not.  The components that do not, seem to be in the place that they would be if they had been rendered on the iPhone.
The weirdest part of this problem is that I can't find anyone online who has had this same issue.  I have already tried deleting and re-installing xcode and the same thing still happens.  I fear I might have to re-install the OS and start from scratch.

How it looks on the iPhone simulator:
[image: iPhone]

And on the iPad simulator:
[image: iPad]

Comment: I don't think that's an SDK issue, I bet that you are writing code that fits for the iPhone screen and not for the larger iPad screen.

Could you post the code and two screenshots, one for the iPhone and one for the iPad results?

Comment: Like I said though, it is the same exact project that everyone else in the office is using, I didn't change the code.  Really, I want to know what would cause this display difference.  I'll see if I can provide screenshots for you though.  I guess I should clarify that everyone else has it render correctly in my office.

Comment: Added screen shots.  It's pretty clear that it's rendering the button at the same coordinates for both simulators instead of scaling it up.  And for those who will complain about the graph being there, it still does this without the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's an SDK issue, I bet that you are writing code that fits for the iPhone screen and not for the larger iPad screen.

I think that you added just the button and is Autoresizing Mask is not set properly. 
I've done some measurement an it seems that:

- The distance from the top of the view is in fixed (~360px);
- The width is fixed (~260px);

You need to give the button a fixed distance from the bottom (as it should stay on under the plot) and remove the left fixed margin so it can be centered.

You need to take a look at the [`UIViewAutoresizingMask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) for the `UIView`'s `autoresizingMask` property.

```
button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Comment: Can you give a code example of how to use this UIViewAutoresizingMask property?  This still does not answer why the same exact project will display differently on two Macs.  I'm looking for an editor setting or something to explain this.  I have tried multiple projects and had the same issue.  I can download examples from the internet and have the same issue.  It's great if setting the button up this way will fix this instance, but if I open a huge project and have to change all the alignments to make it work, this is not a viable option in the long run.

Comment: Could you please tell me if you added the rounded button only on the copy on your mac? The button doesn't have a title so I thought that you added just it.

Comment: This is very weird...   I just reimported all the projects from my workplace and they are rendering fine.  I have no idea why they were all rendering funny before, but now that it's working, idc.  Thanks for trying to help.  And I'm sure your solution for this specific problem will solve it, so I'll mark it as answered.